# Javascript format time military am pm from string

Tags: javascript, datetime

Id it possible to do something like:

```
var format = "ampm";
var time = '22:15:05';

if(format == "ampm") {
   return '10:15 pm';
} else {
   return '22:15';
}
```

All the examples that I found use new Date() with current date and time, but in my case i just need to pass time string from database.

Comment: There's a kajillion date formatting libraries out there. Why not [pick one](https://github.com/nomiddlename/date-format) and use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: convert 24-hour time-of-day string to 12-hour time with AM/PM and no timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898423/javascript-convert-24-hour-time-of-day-string-to-12-hour-time-with-am-pm-and-no)

Comment: @tadman I dont want to use a whole library just for that

Comment: You don't have to use "a whole library", you just need to find the snippet of code in that library that does what you want and put that into your application. Writing your own conversion routine is going to be messy.

Comment: @Rayon Dabre that example show how to convert from 24 hours to 12 hours am/pm but in my case i need both based on setting

Comment: Heard of `if.....else` ?

Comment: Are the time values you want to convert always a string as shown in your code?  Do the strings have a fixed format or can they arrive in any format? Without more information we can only guess at a solution.

Comment: the values are coming from MySql, via Json so the format will always be the same 00:00:00

Comment: Any way to convert standard time to military time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function that you could use:

```js
function timeFormat(time, format) {
    var parts = time.split(':');
    var hour = parseInt(parts[0]);
    var suffix = '';
    if (format === 'ampm') {
       suffix = hour >= 12 ? ' pm' : ' am';
       hour = (hour + 11) % 12 + 1;
    }
    return ('0' + hour).substr(-2) + ':' + parts[1] + suffix;
}

// Demo with some sample input
var input = ['00:21:13', '11:59:20', '12:01:33', '16:00:00', '23:59:59'];
for (var time of input) {
    document.write(time + ' = ' + timeFormat(time, 'ampm') + '<br>');
}
```

Note that it strips the seconds; there is no rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way using if statements.

**Note**: it doesn't take seconds.

```js
const converTime = (time) => {
  let hour = (time.split(':'))[0]
  let min = (time.split(':'))[1]
  let part = hour > 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  
  min = (min+'').length == 1 ? `0${min}` : min;
  hour = hour > 12 ? hour - 12 : hour;
  hour = (hour+'').length == 1 ? `0${hour}` : hour;

  return (`${hour}:${min} ${part}`)
}

console.log(converTime('18:00:00'))
console.log(converTime('6:5:00'))
console.log(converTime('23:58:24'))
```