# angularjs dateTimePicker how to NOT UTC the time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am using [this](https://github.com/zhaber/angular-js-bootstrap-datetimepicker) **`dateTimePicker`** for my angularjs app, and the issue I am having is that what the user enters as time gets translated to a different, UTC based time which differs many hours (screen shot below, the component and the text next to it are both using the same `ng-model`).

[image]

Is there anyway to force this component to produce the output exactly as user enters? like in this case, I would like to get "**2016-05-24 12:00 AM**" out of it!

Comment: Could you post a plunker?

Comment: How are you displaying the text? If you are using the date filter it would have formatted according to the browser timezone by default. You need to add more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the date filter and leave the timezone empty on your date value, leaving the timezone empty will use browser default timezone:

```
{{date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss Z' : ''}}
```

reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Worked perfectly, except I had to change that "Z" to an "a"!

Comment: Excellent! Yes you could define any suitable format for display.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Code :

```
var d = new Date($scope.date);
var day = d.getDate();
var mon = d.getMonth()+1;
var year = d.getFullYear();
var hour = d.getHours();
var min = d.getMinutes();

if(day <10) day = "0"+day;
if(mon <10) mon = "0"+mon;

$scope.newDate = day+"-"+mon+"-"+year+" "+ hour + ":"+ min;
alert($scope.newDate);
```

To convert this 24 hour to 12 hour clock , follow these two question's answers .

[Converting 24 hour time to 12 hour time w/ AM & PM using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898574/converting-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time-w-am-pm-using-javascript)

[Javascript: convert 24-hour time-of-day string to 12-hour time with AM/PM and no timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898423/javascript-convert-24-hour-time-of-day-string-to-12-hour-time-with-am-pm-and-no)