# I am getting error while fetching data in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Here is the API link:

http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=Dubai&country=United%20Arab%20Emirates&method=8

```
<Text>{responseMsg.code}</Text>
<Text>{responseMsg.status}</Text>
```

The above lines are working.
I am able to fetch data from this API like, code, status but I am unable to fetch prayer times from this API. I don't know how to write that line to fetch prayer times from this API.

```
<Text>{(responseMsg.data || []).map(time => time.timings.Fajr)}</Text>
<Text>{(responseMsg.data || []).map(time => time.timings.Dhuhr)}</Text>
```

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating '(responseMsg.data || {}).timings.Fajr')

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: error is: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(responseMsg.data || {}).timings.Fajr')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should directly access the timings because **data** field is object and not an array. What you have to write is :

```
<Text>{(responseMsg.data || {}).timings.Fajr}</Text>
```

Comment: no brother, It's also not working. error is: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(responseMsg.data || {}).timings.Fajr')

Comment: Ohh yes! Because timings key is undefined when data is fetching. May be you can wrap it in ternary like this
`{responseMsg.data && responseMsg.data.timings ? <Text>{responseMsg.data.timings.Fajr}</Text> : null} `

Comment: Or may be you can save it in variable like : 
`const {data = {}} = responseMsg;
const {timings = {}} = data;`

Comment: It is under data > meta > method > name.. {responseMsg.data && responseMsg.data.meta ? <Text>{responseMsg.data.meta.method.name}</Text> : null}..... If i write like this then it's not working

Comment: It worked now brother. thanks for helping. last thing if you can help. i am using geolocation. how can i set geolocation in api link. because api accept city name and geolocation fetches only latitude and longitude.

Comment: you can add a key in the **data** object like : 
`data.location = {
 lat: '' // Latitude value,
long: '' //Longitude value
}`

Comment: brother, can you share your skype id?

Comment: timings are in format like 19:27, can it be like 7:27 pm ?

Comment: You can refer to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898423/javascript-convert-24-hour-time-of-day-string-to-12-hour-time-with-am-pm-and-no

Answer (score 1):

.Map on responseMsg.data won't work as data is an object. Map is a function on arrays not object.

Comment: so how can i write for fetch without .map ?

Comment: No need to use map just access the object directly with 
`responseMsg.data.timings.Fajr`.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer is sooo late ,since i was searching for the same issue

the trick is that in the output json nested objects,ther is another child data object
so to access prayers times :

```
fajr=response.data.data.timings.fajr
```

**yes data.data**

```
timezone=response.data.data.meta.timezone
hijriDay=response.data.data.date.hijri.day
hijriMonth=response.data.data.date.hijri.month.en
hijriYear=response.data.data.date.hijri.year
```