# Display current time in 12 hour time? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add the current time to a website using JS and I found a working solution but the problem is that it works for 24-hour format time and I'm struggling to figure out how I might modify it to display 12-hour format time... See Fiddle HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/7hjsaqdu/1/

```
function display_c() {
  var refresh = 1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()', refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
  var x = new Date()
  var x1 = x.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + x.getDate() + "/" + x.getYear();
  x1 = x1 + " - " + x.getHours() + ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + x.getSeconds();
  var hour = x.getHours();
  var minute = x.getMinutes();
  var second = x.getSeconds();
  if (minute < 10) {
    minute = '0' + minute;
  }
  if (second < 10) {
    second = '0' + second;
  }
  var x3 = hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x3;
  display_c();
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload=display_ct();>
<span id='ct' ></span>
```

Comment: Look like this is exactly what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/13899011/4668680

Answer (score 1):

You can use Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()
[Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString#:%7E:text=Browser%20compatibility%20%20%20%20%20%20Desktop,Full%20support%2011%20%201%20more%20rows%20)

```
let formattedTime = date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
    hour12: true
});

document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = formattedTime;
```