# I want AM and PM along with time in <input type="time">

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Here is the HTML code.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Time From: </mat-label>
    <input matInput type="time" formControlName="start_time">
</mat-form-field>
```

And output after form submitted.

```json
{
   start_time: "00:47"
}
```

Comment: What is your expect output format? Convert `21:57` into `09:57 PM`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: convert 24-hour time-of-day string to 12-hour time with AM/PM and no timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898423/javascript-convert-24-hour-time-of-day-string-to-12-hour-time-with-am-pm-and-no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use moment.js library to get AM/PM with input time.

```
moment(start_time,'hh:mm').format('hh:mm a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use format from date-fns library, moment.js is deprecated

Comment: yes but I have restrictions, I can only use moment