# Converting 24 hour time to 12 hour time w/ AM & PM using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios, routes, vuetify.js, vuex

***DigitalClock.vue***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxQwH.png)

> I want to set the format to 12 with am or pm. I don't know how to fix this, please help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13898423/10720730
Find the solution here

Comment: @Danish I don't know how to apply that to vue.js

Comment: @Danish I'm totally a beginner with this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting 24 hour time to 12 hour time w/ AM & PM using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898574/converting-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time-w-am-pm-using-javascript)

Comment: You can just use the javascript code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898574/converting-24-hour-time-to-12-hour-time-w-am-pm-using-javascript/10885583
 in your function which is inside your methods and there is no need for VUE WAY.